# create styled component with third party component that has custom style props?

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Im using the Slider from react-native-community the component has unique props used to style it, thumbTintColor, minimumTrackTintColor, maximumTrackTintColor, which I need to pass styles to from my themeprovider.  It seems I cant pass props to this component, anyone aware of a way to achieve this?  This is what I have now, and its unfortunately not working.

```
const StyledSlider = styled(Slider)``

export const SurveySlider = props => {
    return (
        <StyledSlider
            style={{
              width: '80%',
              height: 40,
              alignSelf: 'center'
            }}
           minimumValue={0}
           maximumValue={20}
           thumbTintColor={`${props => props.theme.primaryColor}`}
           minimumTrackTintColor={`${props => 
           props.theme.primaryColor}`}
           maximumTrackTintColor={`${props => 
           props.theme.primaryColor}`}
          onValueChange={value => props.onValueChange(value)}
          />
          )
        }
```

Comment: I'm unable to pass colors to the props with colors from my themeprovider ${props=> props.theme.primaryColor}...:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the attrs method supplied by styled components

const StyledSlider = styled(Slider).attrs(props=>{
thumbTintColor:  props.theme.primaryColor
})``

Answer (score 2):

try this:
    minimumTrackTintColor={props.theme.primaryColor}

Comment: unfortunately I get back "undefined is not an object" ('evaluating 'props.theme.primaryColor')

Comment: did you pass down the 'theme' prop from parent component? is 'theme' an object with a key of primaryColor?

Comment: yes I pass theme down, its being applied to other components.  Im passing my theme object down to the ThemeProvider which is wrapping my whole app

Comment: try console.log(props.theme) or console.log(props) to check if you have the theme object passed down to this component.